# What to do with roof vent if needing to drywall over it?

Tags: drywall, insulation, roofing, venting

Heavy DIYer but first time dealing with roof. This is my final trade to learn, so go easy on me. Denver, CO.

I am vaulting the ceiling of what was dead space over the kitchen before. The dead space had a roof vent for the heat.

Given that I will be drywalling the rafters, I'm trying to figure out what to do with existing vents.

There’s one vent that’s just a normal roof vent, and another hole that was the exhaust for the range.

What's the proper way to seal this project up? I don't like taking shortcuts. :)

I plan on swapping insulation to XPS or a high R value fiberglass.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Those vents have no relationship to your drywall. I assuming you have an air/moisture barrier immediately inside the drywall (be it poly sheeting or XPS), they're entirely inconsequential.

If you want to block airflow there as part of your insulation strategy, you can simply staple plastic or housewrap over them, or you could mount a plywood patch using lumber fastened to the rafters. Just don't poke any fasteners into your shingles, even a little.

I would probably ignore them until time comes to replace the roofing, then cut the sheathing back to trusses and install proper plywood patches.

Comment: So you're saying ideally staple plastic over holes, then cover with XPS, moisture barrier, then drywall on rafters? Thanks again for help.

Comment: If you're installing XPS the plastic wouldn't do much to further block airflow. Just think through what each component provides and what it doesn't.

Comment: I think the plywood patch would be more rodent proof.

Comment: Roof vents are typically _already_ rodent-proof.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your entire roof design looks like,  but typically people install "Prop-A-Vents" or equivalent products to facilitate airflow from the soffits up to a ridge vent (or the roof vents like yours).  These are installed up against the roof sheets and then insulation is placed under them & of course prior to placing the ceiling drywall.

The roof itself will  last much longer if it's allowed to track exterior temperatures at all times.

Comment: Have read about these and will plan to install, then insulate. Thanks!